# Google Analytics - Unique Pageview vs Visits

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

Am I correct in assuming that ***Visits*** metric only counts how many times a user started session on the given page, and ***Unique Pageview*** is the number of users whom viewed the given page?

Given the following scenario, I have two pages on my site: *Page A* and *Page B*. *Page A* contains a link to get to *Page B*.

If a user starts browsing my website at *Page A*, *Google Analytics* will increment ***Visits*** and ***Unique Pageviews*** on *A* by 1.

Now if the user were to click on the link to *B*, will *Google Analytics* increment both ***Visits*** and ***Unique Pageviews*** or just ***Unique Pageviews*** on *B*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct in assuming that ‘Visits’ metric only counts how many times a user started session on the given page, and ‘Unique Pageview’ is the number of users whom viewed the given page?

No, pageview is every time tracking code is executed (or _trackPageview() is called) and unique pageviews is the aggregate pageviews that are generated by the same user during the same session.

- [The difference between AdWords Clicks, and Sessions, Users, Entrances, Pageviews, and Unique Pageviews in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en)
- [How a session is defined in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en)

Comment: I didn't take in to account that 'Unique Pageview' can be incremented if  a new session is created. Thanks.

Comment: If you believe I have answered your question to your satisfactory, it is customary to mark it as answered.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked this as two different questions, here is the answer to the scenario: [link](http://www.akravitz.com/when-visits-arent-visits/). So, only Unique Pageviews will be incremented, not visits.

Comment: According to your referenced article (at the bottom) it says `UPDATE: As of June, 2012, GA has acknowledged the issue with “visits” in the page-level custom variable report by replacing it with a new metric called Visit Starts.` So now if your making custom reports it will be different and you will select 'Visit Starts'

Comment: Update to sessions in Google analytics: http://analytics.blogspot.ca/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

Question: Now if the user were to click on the link to B, will Google Analytics increment both Visits and Unique Pageviews or just Unique Pageviews on B?
Answer: Visit (not increase) / Unique pageviews on Page B (+1)

Basically, visits is the first hit of session, it may differ to entrances (the first pageview hit of a session). Please see the below link.

link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2524483

It's the example by Google
Visit 1:

```
Visitor enters to Page A
Visitor navigates to Page B
Visitor navigates back to Page A
End of session
```

Visit 2:

```
Visitor enters to Page C
Visitor navigates to Page B
End of session
```

Summary

```
Page A: 2 Page views, 1 Visit, 1 Unique Page view, 1 Unique Visitor, 1 Entrance
Page B: 2 Page views, 0 Visits, 2 Unique Page views, 2 Unique Visitors, 0 Entrances
Page C: 1 Page view, 1 Visit, 1 Unique Page view, 1 Unique Visitor, 1 Entrance
Totals: 5 Page views, 2 Visits, 4 Unique Page views, 2 Unique Visitors, 2 Entrances
```